# Unable to write multiple values back to ACF user field (PHP. Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My project is to make an initial match of mentors & mentees users. And then add multiple mentees to a mentor.

My mentor has an ACF current_mentees (list of users) field. I am able to add one user to that.
But when I try to push/add another one, it doesn't add the 2nd one.

```
// get mentor & new mentee user arrays from the Match Metadata fields
$mentor = get_field('match_mentor', $post_id);
$mentee = get_field('match_mentee', $post_id);

//get ID from mentor array
$match_mentor_id = $mentor['ID'];  
//get ID from mentee array
$match_mentee_id = $mentee['ID'];

//set up the mentor user_post_id
$mentor_post_id = "user_".$match_mentor_id; 

//get mentor curent_users contents
$current_mentees = get_field('current_mentees', $mentor_post_id, false);

// see if the current mentees is null or has a mentee already
if ($current_mentees == ''){

    //write new current mentees back to the Mentor User Meta fields
    update_field('current_mentees' , $match_mentee_id , $mentor_post_id);

       } else {

   //combine old mentee(s) with new mentee
   array_push( $current_mentees , $match_mentee_id);

//write new current mentees back to the Mentor User Meta fields
update_field('current_mentees' , $current_mentees , $mentor_post_id);
```

The match_mentor & match_mentee and current_mentees are all ACF fields.
I am able to manually add (mentee) users (single & multiple) to the current_mentees through the dropdown in the user account. It appears as an array of arrays.
The first one looks like: a:1:{i:0;s:2:”60″;} //user 60
Adding the second one gives me: a:2:{i:0;s:2:”60″;i:1;s:2:”57″;}  //users 60 & 57
This is functional for my purpose. I’d like the code to do the same.

But... using the above code to add one user, in the current_mentees field/DB I see 60.
And then adding the 2nd one, I get a:1:{i:0;i:57;}. (It replaces the first one instead of adding a 2nd user).

I'm not sure if this is starting off wrong (with the first user), or if I need to change my variables at some point before adding the 2nd (which I've tried). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had thought of a couple ideas to try this morning, and things came together. Let me post my revised code. Essentially, I tried to follow the natural formatting to see if I could get everything to fall in line further along. I decided to convert the initial variable to an array, and that is what made everything else fall in line.

```
// get mentor & new mentee user arrays from the Match Metadata fields
$mentor = get_field(‘match_mentor’, $post_id);
$mentee = get_field(‘match_mentee’, $post_id);

//get ID from mentor array
$match_mentor_id = $mentor[‘ID’];

//get ID from mentee array
$match_mentee_id = $mentee[‘ID’];

//set up the mentor user_post_id
$mentor_post_id = “user_”.$match_mentor_id;

//get user array from mentor curent_users
$current_mentees = get_field(‘current_mentees’, $mentor_post_id, false);

// see if the current mentees is null or has a mentee already
if ($current_mentees == ”) {
    //put data in proper format
    $current_mentees = array();
}

//combine old mentee(s) with new mentee
array_push( $current_mentees , $match_mentee_id);

//write new current mentees back to the Mentor User Meta fields
update_field(‘current_mentees’ , $current_mentees , $mentor_post_id);
```